# Android, when GridView nested in a ListView, it width will fill_parent even it's child is just one

Tags: android, listview, gridview, nested, scrollview

Android, when GridView nested in ScrollView or ListView, it's width will fill_parent even it's child is just one, i want it's width is wrap_content, any sulotion ? thanks.
   the listview item xml like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp" >
</TextView>

<com.umeng.example.communitydemo.MGridView
    android:id="@+id/my_gv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="#aaaaaa"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the MGridView is :

```
public class MGridView extends GridView {

public boolean hasScrollBar = true;

/**
 * @param context
 */
public MGridView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public MGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, 0);
}

public MGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int expandSpec = heightMeasureSpec;
    if (hasScrollBar) {
        expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

}

```
 two screen shot : http://pan.baidu.com/s/1c06Gfny。
```

Comment: Why you are using Gridview inside ScrollView ?

Comment: Gridview and listview are vertically scrollable by default , you need not put them in scroll view.

Comment: Putting a vertical scrollable inside another one is a **VERY BAD practice**

Comment: Actually, it is gridview nested in listview, like facebook's timeline page ( sns app)。two screen shot : http://pan.baidu.com/s/1c06Gfny。

Comment: i fixed it, and share it to github: https://github.com/bboyfeiyu/listview_nested_gridview。